# Htaccess Basic Auth for Wordpress site - need exception for one page

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, authentication

I have a Wordpress site that's still in development and is locked with basic auth in a .htaccess file. However, I need to make a pre-quote questionnaire page visible to a potential client now.

I have followed a lot of similar threads (about allowing url's or directories as an exception) and I have it almost working but I have to keep cancelling the login prompt repeatedly. Also, the page does load, but without stlyes and scripts.

Would htaccess be blocking the style and script links the page loads from  ? If so, would I need to make another SetEnvIf Request_URI entry for each?

Here is my .htaccess currently

```
SetEnvIf Request_URI "(questionnaire/)$" q-url

AuthType Basic
AuthName "Development Area"
AuthUserFile "/XXXX/.htpasswds/public_html/passwd"
Require valid-user
Satisfy any
Order allow,deny
Deny from all
Allow from env=q-url


# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
# END WordPress
</IfModule>
```

Apache version is 2.4.7

Cheers!